# gnuplottex: conversion failed

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplottex

Getting this errors:

```
Package gnuplottex Warning: Conversion of ap-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot failed.
Package gnuplottex Warning: Please convert ap-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot manually.
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}
set terminal epslatex color size 14cm,12cm

plot x**2
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

I use texmaker

pdflatex command:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify the terminal and terminal options as options to the `gnuplottex` environment:

```
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions={color size 14cm,12cm}]
```

And you'll also need the `xcolor` package in your case. Full working example:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions={color size 14cm,12cm}]
plot x**2
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but i`m still getting the same errors with your example.

Comment: In file %.gnuploterrors there is:
`line 0: Cannot open script file 'ap-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot'`

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce the error. The above works without problems for me.